# File in folder created before folder itself

Tags: python, directory

I have got an interesting behavior while reading folder and file in folder creation times. Could someone explain this?

Creating *folder*

```
os.makedirs(version_dir+test_name)
```

Running sub-process in this folder and create *result file* there

```
err_code = common.run_proc(common.get_root_dir() + test_name, custom_path_str=version_dir+test_name)
```

Then there is another script where I read creation time of *folder* and *result file* using `os.get.getmtime` and apparently creation (as I understood from docs this is modification time) time of the file within folder is `1403197510.1` and for folder itself is `1403197510.19`.
So basicly I have created file in not existing folder. How does this really work or why do I have such a strange output?

Comment: If getmtime is modification time then it is obviously not creation time. What is your question here?

Comment: Yes, I have found that there is also `os.get.getctime()` function that returns creation time. But what I wanted to know is what @Shadow9043 is talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you are seeing is the fact that Windows will modify the folders to represent the files within.

So this happens:

- os.makedirs() creates folder, gives you time of modification (with os.path.getmtime).
  e.g. 1403197510.0
- Write file to folder, gives you time of modification (with os.path.getmtime). e.g.
  1403197510.1
- Windows updates Folder, gives you modification time (with os.path.getmtime). e.g.
  1403197510.19